# Trying to decode a NASDAQ binary file. what kind of codec do those use ? tried utf-8, unicode-escape and acsii

Tags: python

Getting this error with each and every codec I have tried so far.

```
 UnicodeDecodeError: 
   'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: ordinal not in range(128).
```

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that it's something that can be decoded into Unicode characters at all? If it's a packed binary format that calls for a completely different set of tools.

Comment: What data are you decoding?  Can you provide a hex dump or something?